# What layout in android should be used to achieve the following buttons?

Tags: android, facebook, button

I have built an hybrid app which has the following buttons in the following format for twitter and facebook:

[image]

I am trying to rebuld the two buttons in Android but I always have a gap in between and I always have to mess around with the dp to bring them together.

is there a good way to make the button in Android like in the picture ?

Just need some recommendations.

Thank you

Comment: @Nant make a look on my answer it will fulfill your need

Comment: @Tony I will look today in the evening. Much appreciated thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution would be to use a TextView instead of a Button, set a background as an XML selector (you can create a rectangle with only rounded corners in one side if that's what you want). Set the margins to zero on the textviews so they touch.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/your_drawable_here"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:text="Left button" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/your_drawable_here"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:text="Right button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I would use an image view (they are images) but this is the answer-  don't use button if you don't want it to look like a button.

Comment: @Francesc how can I make the textview smaller from left and right ?

Comment: You can add left/right margins. Add left margin to the left textview, and right margin to the right textview. Alternatively add padding to the container for the textviews (the linear layout).

Answer (score 1):

Here is the background drawable

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#fff"/>

    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="3dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="3dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="3dp"
        android:topRightRadius="3dp"/>

    </shape>

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#199fd4"/>

    <corners
        android:bottomRightRadius="3dp"
        android:topRightRadius="3dp"/>

</shape>

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#1f19d4"/>

    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="3dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="0dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="3dp"
        android:topRightRadius="0dp"/>

</shape>
```

then you need to create linear layout and place the two button inside of it with 50% for each one you can set this using weight attribute

Layout code

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
    android:background="@drawable/roundedallsides_white"
    android:weightSum="2">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_left"></RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_right"></RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

and inside those two relative layouts you can place any thing you want and then set on click listener on them